# Connection Strings/Settings in Azure Portal - is it a xdt:Transform="SetAttributes", a xdt:Transform="Insert" or hybrid?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I was recently having a problem with a site and the stack trace was implying that the connectionstring was null. This is after i moved (i.e. cut the node out of the xml file, pasted it into portal) the connstr from web.config to azure portal, so the connstr wasn't referenced the web config at all

In a video blog, Scott Hanselman talked about the portal settings overriding the web.config ones, but there was never any detail on what whether the key had to be present in the deployed web config for the azure portal value to be applied

This raises a query in my mind - if a setting isn't in the web.config at all (i.e. there is no xml node saying `<add key="blah" value="debugblah" />`), will the setting in the portal work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if a setting isn't in the web.config at all (i.e. there is no xml node saying `<add key="blah" value="debugblah" />`), will the setting in the portal work?

The short answer is Yes. To simple test it, you could using following code.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string appSetting1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["setting1"];
    string connectionString1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString1"]?.ConnectionString;
    return Content(string.Format("appSetting1:{0},connectionString1：{1}", appSetting1, connectionString1));
}
```

After added parameters in Azure portal, we could get the app setting and connection string from ConfigurationManager.

[image]

Here is the result from index page.

```
appSetting1:setting1Value,connectionString1：connectionString1Value
```

There is an exception when we use connection string for Entity Framework. A connection string for EF will contain a providerName attribute which can't be set in Azure portal. So if we need a connection string setting with providerName, we need to configure the connection string in config file.

```
<add name="DataContext" connectionString="dummy" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Does this answer still bear true if there are two sites and a trafficmanager involved? As far as I was aware, there isn't much the two sites have to do with each other, and the trafficmanager is just a switching device, maybe taking part in config only as far as a shared domain name/binding the host header.. But then I became uncertain because I was seeing these really odd errors where nHibernate was complaining the connectionstring was null when it was defined only in the portal, not in web config.. If I added it to web config it all worked. The next odd thing was the Redis cache: it has a..

Comment: ..connection string parameter to specify which cache db# to use. In the portal conenction string i set db 0, in the web config I initially left the conenction string absent, and it was crashing with null reference error (conn str was null).. so I added it to the web config, all starts working, but data is being put in the db# specified in the portal, not the web config.. hence my initial query. I've now implemented a page like you receommend, to dump the config and I can test more, thanks!

Comment: App setting in web app will not affected by traffic manager. Please tell me the test result if you followed my suggestion.

Comment: For Redis cache, please check whether you have choose ‘Redis Cache’ for connection string type in Azure portal.

Comment: Now there's a thing. Once upon a time, "Redis Cache" was not an option for connection string - back when the production environment was set up. When setting up prod staging environment i DID initially choose Redis Cache option, but I have since altered it to be "Custom" like prod. I've been moved off this project for a couple of weeks now, but as soon as I can get back to it I will give you an update..

Comment: Have you tested it? If you don't have any question about this topic, please close this thread by marking helpful replies as answer.

Comment: Hi Amor. I haven't tested it yet - next due to look at this project again next week. Sorry for the delay, but I'm the only dev in a too-busy organization

Comment: Hi Amor, I've tested your answer not a non-traffic-manager-enrolled site and it seems what you say is correct: `If the key is only in Azure portal, portal value is used. If the key is only in Web.Config, web.config value is used. If the key is in both web.config and portal, portal value is used`

Answer (score 1):

> is it a xdt:Transform=“SetAttributes”, a xdt:Transform=“Insert” or hybrid?

**It is a hybrid**

or, possibly

**Portal does a remove, followed by an insert**

Which means:

- If the setting is only configured in portal.azure.com then your app will see the value set in portal.azure.com
- If the setting is only configured in the web.config file in the wwwroot folder, then your app will see the value set in the web.config file
- If the setting is configured in both portal.azure.com AND the web.config file, then the app will see the value set in portal.azure.com

So don't worry if you upload your debug/dev configs to a live site, if the portal settings contain the live settings details :)

Thanks to Amor for the method used to verify this

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it will work.**

The setting does not have to be present in the `web.config` file.  If it is present in the Web App's *Connection Strings* or *Application Settings* (set in the portal or via AzureRM), then it will be visible to the application.